# Jquery, execute a function after previous one is complete in cascade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i need some expert to show how can i achieve this.
i have this html code that is part of a multiple choice (from A to E) question

```
<div id="correct-answer-XXXXX" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="wrong-answer-XXXXX" style="display:none;"></div>
```

And i also have this jquery ajax code that submit to a remote URL (wich i dont have acess to the code) and changes one of those divs above, changing the status from display 'style' to 'block' and hiding the other one, in other words, show if your answer is right or wrong.

```
var vector = new Array('A','B','C','D','E');
var i = 0;
  function answerquestion(XXXXX,choice){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        data:{choice},
        url:"http://myremoteurl.com/"+XXXXX,
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        complete:function(){
          var style = $("#correct-answer-"+XXXXX).css("display");
          if (style == "block") {
            //ill do something with the correct answer 
          } else {
            i++;
            answerquestion(XXXXX,vector[i]);
          }
        }
      })
  }
```

That code works fine for one question, but i need to execute this function in sequence, lets say, 60 to 100 times in a row, and when i got the answer of the first one, run the second one

i have a div filled with fields containing the data XXXXX, so i can use those fields to get the XXXXX variable in some kind of loop for example:

```
<div id="fieldscontainer">
<input type="hidden" name="111111" value="111111">
<input type="hidden" name="222222" value="222222">
<input type="hidden" name="333333" value="333333">
...
<input type="hidden" name="XXXXXX" value="XXXXXX">
</div>
```

So the only way to get the correct answer is getting the style of div correct-answer-XXXXX, but a simple $.each loop wont help since the functon itself must run a few times until finds the right answer

Heres a picture ilustrating what i want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I recommend to learn about promises: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/. Maybe looking at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+Execute+Ajax+calls+in+series helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
async : false

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    async : false, /// add this line
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And how do i execute the function for each line, how async will help with this, see the table, each row have a field, <input type="hidden" name="111111" value="111111"> i need to run one at a atime for each inpu

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question.